# Drawing a function to <DIV>

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks for reading and helping. I'm trying to use a function that draws a Dial in a specific div but isn't working. I know this works for text:

```
<div id="content">
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "hi";
</script>
```

But what if i want to write some function there? How can i do that? Imagine i have this:

```
<div id="content">
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = somefunction();

function somefunction(){
document.write("hi");
}
</script>
```

I know that if i use return it work's but i want to know if there's a way to do it without return.

Thank you so much!

EDIT:

I'm going to be more specific. Imagine i have this:

```
<div id="content">
</div>

<script>    
function createDial(){
document.write("<input class='knob' data-min='-15000' data-max='15000' value='-11000'>)
}
</script>
```

That input creates a Dial (see http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ if you don't know that i'm refering to). Now, having this, can i a draw the Dial in "content"?

Thanks all and i'm sorry for my english!

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? Your question isn't clear

Comment: As you're using an assignment, you'll have to use the return value of the function. No way around it. If you'll absolutely want to avoid the return, you'll have to restructure your code.

Answer (score 2):

Return string for `somefunction` instead of `document.write`

```
function somefunction(){
  return "hi";
}
```

You can pass element name to function and assign html in to element there.

```
function somefunction(elementId){
   document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "hi";
}
```

Comment: Yes, like i wrote i know that works but i want to know if there's a way to do it without that, because i have a function that draws a Dial and i want to put it in a specific div.

Comment: @user1722670 Seeing this comment, I guess you'll have to do a bit of research. So you'll get a better general understanding of how the DOM works in a browser.

Comment: @Adil JSLint would throw: `Unused variables: elementName` ; ).

Comment: Thanks @Teemu, so nice of you.

Comment: I edited the answer to be more specific, thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to get this work without returning a value, you can do something like this:

```
function somefunction (elm) {
    elm.innerHTML = '<input class="knob" data-min="-15000" data-max="15000" value="-11000">';
    $(".knob").knob();
}
somefunction(document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but that's not exactly the problem. I edited the answer :)

Comment: @user1722670 I'm not sure if this is what you mean. Instead I'm sure you can't use `document.write()` after the page has been parsed, since it'll clear the whole document, only what is left is the HTML written by that function.

Answer (score 0):

All i needed is this (I think Yoshi referred to this too):

```
$( "#content" ).append("whatever you want, even an input or something else");
```

That's why I tagged with jQuery before.